# How can I create a patch using Git?

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I have found an issue on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org) that I would like to submit an solution for. How can I create a patch using git so that I can submit it as a possible fix?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every Drupal.org project has a tab title 'Version control', click on it and it will take you to a page with Git instructions, including a section titled 'Creating a patch'.

See here for an example: http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_fields/git-instructions

Code below is copied from the D.o. instructions.

```
git checkout -b [description]-[issue-number]
```

Make your changes. Note the change in syntax for issue-related commit messages. See the [Commit messages](http://drupal.org/node/1061754) page for details.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Issue #[issue number] by [comma-separated usernames]: [Short summary of the change]."
```

Roll the patch.

```
git status
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/6.x-1.x
git format-patch origin/6.x-1.x --stdout > [description]-[issue-number]-[comment-number].patch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PhpStorm or IntelliJ you can do the following:

- Make sure your branch is up-to-date (commit everything)
- Make the changes (fix the bug)
- Go to VCS > Create patch

  [image: Go to VCS > Create patch]
- Follow the steps and save where you prefer it.

  [image: Follow the steps and save where you prefer it]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't overcomplicate things. In the end all you really need is a dev version of the module, init an empty Git repo in it, clean the working tree (commit everything, it's just locally), make your changes and then run the following command.

```
$ git diff > [short_description]-[issue-number]-[comment-number].patch
```

---

In a steb-by-step that maybe boils down to the following.

1. Have a local Drupal running you can mess around with.
2. Download a dev version of the module into your local Drupal's contrib modules folder.
3. Now `cd` into the module's directory and `git init`, then `git add .` and `git commit -m "Clean tree"` to have a clean state to start from.
4. Do your code changes, and use the local Drupal to check if everything's working and in the end run the `git diff` command from above.
5. Upload the patch on drupal.org and set the issue to "Needs review".